# Making loops into functions so the GUI can search and respond to change text with results

Tags: function, dictionary, for-loop, tkinter, while-loop

I am trying to search through a list of elements and return values that were not provided.
So far i can get it to work as a basic computer program, but I am having trouble integrating it to tkinter. I am playing with the program here and there to get things moving. I understand that I may need to convert some of my loops to functions.

```
#Loop to run through elements dictionry and make list of the values there
result = []
for element, element_dict in elements.items(): #for (new variable made in for loop), () in (dictionary elements, but .items() designates just the values)
    if (givenInfo in element_dict):
        result = list(element_dict)
        break
```

needs to be switched to a function so i can call it with my search button.

I also believe:

```
#assigns givenInfo to new type so it can be searched
if givenInfo.isdigit():
    givenInfo = int(givenInfo)
elif givenInfo.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit():
    givenInfo = float(givenInfo)
else:
    givenInfo = givenInfo.capitalize()
```

and

```
#Loop to assign each value to its proper designation
i=0
while i < len(result):
    if type(result[i]) is int:
        atomNum = result[i]
        print("The atomic number is:", atomNum)
        i+=1
    elif type(result[i]) is float:
        atomMass = result[i]
        print("The atomic mass is:", atomMass)
        i+=1
    elif type(result[i]) is str and len(result[i]) > 2:
        name = result[i]
        print("The element name:", name)
        i+=1
    elif type(result[i]) is str and len(result[i]) <= 2:
        symbol = result[i]
        print("The symbol for the element:", symbol)
        i+=1
    else:
        print(type(result[i]))
        i+=1
```

may need to be converted. Once that is done i should be able to tie the commands to search button so i can search with the GUI app and have it change the text listed below.

full code:

```
from tkinter import *
from periodicTable import elements

#RELIC
givenInfo = input("please enter an the information you were given about the element, and I will enter the info for it:") #prompt for what they were provided
#RELIC

#if else route to designate each entry of givenInfo as str, int, or float
if givenInfo.isdigit():
    givenInfo = int(givenInfo)
elif givenInfo.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit():
    givenInfo = float(givenInfo)
else:
    givenInfo = givenInfo.capitalize()



#The proper designations for the data, for the start, it is all empty
name = ""
symbol = ""
atomNum = 0
atomMass = 0


#Loop to run through elements dictionry and make list of the values there
result = [] #List needed 
for element, element_dict in elements.items(): #for (new variable made in for loop), () in (dictionary elements, but .items() designates just the values)
    if (givenInfo in element_dict):
        result = list(element_dict)
        break

#RELIC
print(givenInfo)        
#print(result)
#RELIC

#Loop to assign each value to its proper designation
i=0
while i < len(result):
    if type(result[i]) is int:
        atomNum = result[i]
        print("The atomic number is:", atomNum)
        i+=1
    elif type(result[i]) is float:
        atomMass = result[i]
        print("The atomic mass is:", atomMass)
        i+=1
    elif type(result[i]) is str and len(result[i]) > 2:
        name = result[i]
        print("The element name:", name)
        i+=1
    elif type(result[i]) is str and len(result[i]) <= 2:
        symbol = result[i]
        print("The symbol for the element:", symbol)
        i+=1
    else:
        print(type(result[i]))
        i+=1
#______________________________________________________________Margin from main program engine______________________________________________________________#
root = Tk()

#myText=givenInfo;

firstframe = Frame(root)
firstframe.pack()

secondframe= Frame(root)
secondframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )


#Text label prompt for what user was provided in the problem label in row 0
Label(firstframe, text='What were you provded for the element?').grid(row=0)

#Result1 label in row 1
Label(firstframe, text=f"{'The symbol for the element is: '+ symbol}").grid(row=1) #this line prints the result as needed

#Result2 label in row 2
Label(firstframe, text='result2 this might be the atomic number').grid(row=2)

#Result3 label in row 3
Label(firstframe, text='result3 this might be the atomic mass').grid(row=3)

#Result4 label in row 4
Label(firstframe, text='The atomic number is:').grid(row=4)

#entry field
entry = Entry(firstframe)
#place it next to "what were you given"
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)



#answer label adjacent to label Result , so row 2 column 1
Label(firstframe,text="",textvariable=givenInfo).grid(row=2,column=1)

#creating a search button. Clicking the button should initiate the search through the dictionary.
#command attribute is for on click event.
searchButton = Button(secondframe, text ='Search')
searchButton.pack()

#creating a new button, should clear the results when clicked.
clearButton = Button(secondframe, text ='Clear')
clearButton.pack()

#creating a new window to search another element with
newWindowButton = Button(secondframe, text="New Window", command=root.mainloop)
newWindowButton.pack()

#creating a Celsius to Exit button. root.destroy will exit the window
exitbutton = Button(secondframe, text ='Exit', fg ='red', command=root.destroy)
exitbutton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

and the dictionary is structured like:

```
elements = {
    'hydrogen': {'Hydrogen', 'H', 1, 1.0080}, 
    'helium': {'Helium', 'He', 2, 4.0026},  
    'lithium': {'Lithium', 'Li', 3, 7.0000}, 
    'beryllium': {'Beryllium', 'Be',  4, 9.0121}, 
    'boron': {'Boron', 'B', 5, 10.81}, 
    'carbon': {'Carbon', 'C', 6, 12.011}, 
    'nitrogen': {'Nitrogen', 'N', 7, 14.007},
    'oxygen': {'Oxygen', 'O', 8, 15.999}, 
    'fluorine': {'Fluorine', 'F', 9, 18.9984}, 
    'neon': {'Neon', 'Ne', 10, 20.180}, 
    'sodium': {'Sodium', 'Na', 11, 22.9898}, 
    'magnesium': {'Magnesium', 'Mg', 12, 24.305}
}
```

Comment: You might find [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/272438/228833) helpful.

Comment: that was insightful, but my goal is to return values based off what the user entered. This real periodic table is elaborate, but i am not understanding their functions in relation to my loops